# Ruby on Rails accessing sessions by its id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a ReactJS App. The app sends a request to the Rails App, in which the rails app generates a unique ID, `session[:app_session]` for the session and returns it. This value is kept for validating data during the session.

Because the cookies are not preserved on the request, I cannot access the value by the variable by a simple `session[:app_session]` in the rails app.

However, I can preserve the session id in the ReactJS app. Then, I can send that session ID along with the request to the rails app. So the question is, is there any way I can get the `session[:app_session]` by using that `session_id`, something like `get_session_by_id('5fdc58f1799f8d216aec04827c2add5c')`?

Comment: so you're not using cookiestore to store the sessions?

Comment: nope, the authentication is handled using JWT tokens. Not keeping track of any cookies at this moment.

Comment: It might depend on how you're storing your sessions. for example in memcache store there seems to be support for what you want http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Session/Memcache#get_session-instance_method